# Conditional Distribution of Bivariate Truncated normal

Tags: probability, normal-distribution

Does anyone know a result for the density of a truncated normal distribution conditional on a correlated truncated normal distribution? Only needs to be truncated bellow at 0 if that makes it easier. I was hoping the 
the bivariate normal distribution result would apply but I don't think it does.
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multivariate_normal_distribution#Bivariate_case

Cheers
Angus

Comment: Do you mean you have a bivariate normal $(X, Y)$, and then truncated on the rectangular region, say $[a, b] \times [c, d]$, and then you ask for the conditional distribution?

Comment: Good question, I haven't been very specific. Yes let's say there is a Bivariate normal (X,Y) that is truncated on region. For simplicity let's keep the region the same in each dimension so it's just [a,b] x [a,b].  What is the conditional distribution of Y|(X=x , a<Y<b, a<x<b) ?

Answer (score 0):

The conditional distribution is a truncated normal distribution according to the paper "Some Results on the Multivariate Truncated
Normal Distribution" by Horrace (2005). 
But the paper does not give the moments of conditional distribution though.
If the link is still active, See
https://surface.syr.edu/cgi/viewcontent.cgi?article=1149&context=ecn

Comment: This is not a link-only answer.  It gives an actual answer and then provides a link as a reference with more details.